# Append won't work in Linked List of Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list, nodes

This is my class

```
class NumberList
{
private:
   // Declare a structure for the list
   struct ListNode
   {
      double value[10];           // The value in this node
      struct ListNode *next;  // To point to the next node
   }; 

   ListNode *head;            // List head pointer

public:
   // Constructor
   NumberList()
      { head = nullptr; }

   // Destructor
   ~NumberList();

   // Linked list operations
   void appendNode(double []);
   void insertNode(double []);
   void deleteNode(double []);
   void displayList() const;
};
```

This is my append function and I can't get it to work -- i keep getting an error message.

```
void NumberList::appendNode(double num[])
{
   ListNode *newNode;  // To point to a new node
   ListNode *nodePtr;  // To move through the list

   // Allocate a new node and store num there.
   newNode = new ListNode;
   newNode->value = num;
   newNode->next = nullptr;

   // If there are no nodes in the list
   // make newNode the first node.
   if (!head)
      head = newNode;
   else  // Otherwise, insert newNode at end.
   {
      // Initialize nodePtr to head of list.
      nodePtr = head;

      // Find the last node in the list.
      while (nodePtr->next)
         nodePtr = nodePtr->next;

      // Insert newNode as the last node.
      nodePtr->next = newNode;
   }
}
```

Error message:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘void NumberList::appendNode(double*)’: prog.cpp:40:19: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘double*’ to ‘double [10]’ newNode->value = num;
```

Any suggestions about what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you want to put a & in front of newnode->value or do it like &newnode->value[0] but it's been a while since I worked with C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of the parameter `num` in `void NumberList::appendNode(double num[])` is really a pointer (= `double*`), rather than an array with a defined number of elements.

Using `std::array<double,10>` in your structure and as the parameter to `appendNode` would be a good solution.

This:

```
struct ListNode
{
  double value[10];
...
```

Becomes:

```
struct ListNode
{
  std::array<double,10> value;
...
```

And your function parameters would be declared as:

```
void appendNode(const std::array<double,10>& num);
```

`newNode->value = num;` requires no change.

Comment: where would i change that declaration - newNode->value = num[]; or in the function parameter?

Comment: C arrays know their size (or at least it forms part of their type). It just gets lost if you pass them to a function that takes a pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong but someone help me rewrite the function in full it just seems to be not working on my end.

Comment: @juanchopanza clarified

Comment: Got it -- thank you. One more question -- I have updated the code and now get a message in main that says: Runtime error time: 0 memory: 3424 signal:11. `NumberList list;
double arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}; 
list.appendNode(arr);`

Comment: @YelizavetaYR you're welcome. just change the declaration of `arr` from `double arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};` to `std::array<double,10> arr = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}};`